# Top tags and Top posts are coming in row format in my profile?

Tags: support, design, profile-page

Top tags and top posts are showing up row-wise pretty neat and tidy for my profile. Is it just for my profile or do have an update on the SO Profile page?

[image: Top Tags]

[image]

Comment: [Now live: A fully responsive profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370964/818993)

Comment: I guess we'll have to disagree on that. I think it's too spacey. It puts emphasis in all the wrong places. It neglects the fact that menus are suppose to appear on the top. And the top tags are now taking up double the space that it used to while making the actual tags tiny..

Comment: Tis the nature of "responsive design". Rather than having different results to best compliment the device the page is viewed on, we get one that often favors one over the rest. (can you guess which this design favors?)

Comment: @KevinB Portrait Overflow design...